# Issue with Lollipop upgrade on Micromax Yureka: Unable to pick calls

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, calls, micromax-yu-yureka

Yesterday I got an update to upgrade my Micromax Yureka mobile to CyanogenMod 12 which upgrades the Android version to Lollipop. And from then I am unable to pick calls, as nothing gets displayed/or rather display won't turn on to pick up the call.

I installed a sensor test app and found that the proximity and light sensors are not working. I removed the screen protector as well. Can someone please suggest a fix for it?

Comment: Which ROM did you upgrade from? You may need to flash an updated modem.

Comment: Go to yuplaygod forums you will get more suggestions !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please dial this code: `*#*#7769#*#*`, and after that click on start. It will automatically resolve the issue.