# Major issues on Micromax YUREKA after updating to Lollipop

Tags: connection-issues, mobile-data, data-connection, micromax-yu-yureka, camera-flash

I am having multiple issues on my Micromax Yureka after upgrading to Lollipop:

1. I am unable to pick up calls & the display is not coming on
2. USB storage connection is not functioning & won't connect to the computer
3. Unable to stop the mobile data when it's already connected, when I click the data option, it's going the open the data usage details only.
4. Rear camera flash not properly functioning, it's not timely flashing.

How can I fix the issues?

Comment: I've added the [tag:micromax-yu] tag, there have been a lot of questions similar to this recently. I recommend you have a look and see if any of them help to resolve your issues.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! To make it easier to identify the relevant questions, [I've linked the related search for "Yureka Lollipop" questions having answers](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=yureka+lollipop+answers%3A1). #2 & #3 might be solved here: [Internet & Play Store problem on Micromax Yureka on Lollipop](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/106575/16575), #1 is here: [Issue with Lollipop upgrade on Micromax Yureka: Unable to pick calls](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/106070/16575). …

Comment: … So please [edit] your question, remove 1-3, and leave only #4: The question-and-answer format of this site works best if you [put each question in a separate question post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/192154).

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Dialpad.
2. Dial `*#*#7769#*#*`
3. A proximity sensor calibration window will pop up.
4. Press “Start”
5. The sensor will be automatically calibrated, a message will appear “ Calibration Good”